# Getting most frequent item in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using this code to get the most played song in a collection by the number of times it appears in the database:

```
public Cursor getMostPlayed(){
    String query = "SELECT * " +
            ", COUNT(*) AS 'value'" +
            " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COLLECTIONS_TRACKS +
            " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_CATEGORY + " = 'User Activity'" +
            " GROUP BY " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME +
            " ORDER BY 'value' DESC";

    return database.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Problem is, when I query the cursor to get the results, while it does get the most played item, it doesn't order the list by value, but rather by the name.

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the string delimiters around the `value` alias.

```
String query = "SELECT * " +
        ", COUNT(*) AS value" +
        " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COLLECTIONS_TRACKS +
        " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_CATEGORY + " = 'User Activity'" +
        " GROUP BY " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME +
        " ORDER BY value DESC";
```